# FragmentPagerAdapter - Create dynamic content for each fragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have implement FragmentPagerAdapter in my app but it show only a same list of items for each fragment whenever i swipe. I am using SherlockFragmentActivity and i want to show different non static pages for each fragment whenever i swipe to next or previous fragment in fragment pager.

How can i do so ?

Have i listed a list of contacts without any title of the current fragment so that i could know that this is my contacts fragment in my fragment using this code

```
public class ContactsFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

     // This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data.
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    // If non-null, this is the current filter the user has provided.
    String mCurFilter;



    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context){
        ContactsFragment contactFragment = new ContactsFragment();
        return contactFragment;
    }


    @Override 
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Give some text to display if there is no data.  In a real
        // application this would come from a resource.
       // setEmptyText("No phone numbers");


        // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.

        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
                new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1}, 0);


        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Start out with a progress indicator.
        setListShown(true);

        // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
        // or start a new one.
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    }



    @Override public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Insert desired behavior here.
        Log.i("FragmentComplexList", "Item clicked: " + id);
    }

    // These are the Contacts rows that we will retrieve.
    static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
    };

    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
         // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created.  This
        // sample only has one Loader, so we don't care about the ID.
        // First, pick the base URI to use depending on whether we are
        // currently filtering.
        Uri baseUri;
        if (mCurFilter != null) {
            baseUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                      Uri.encode(mCurFilter));
        } else {
            baseUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        }

        // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
        // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
        String select = "((" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri,
                CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
        // old cursor once we return.)
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);

        // The list should now be shown.
        if (isResumed()) {
            setListShown(true);
        } else {
            setListShownNoAnimation(true);
        }
    }

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
        // above is about to be closed.  We need to make sure we are no
        // longer using it.
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }


}
```

But I want to show tile above the contact list. For this i put two more methods in my fragment class which i have listed below

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ((TextView)tv).setText("Contacts");
        return v;
    }
```

But when i run my app " Your app stopped unexpetedly" this popup mesage is come.

Without these methods my app is working fine but without any title of fragment. Whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you can achieve this using view pager here the [exmple](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/)

you can use this in your one.xml layout

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/List" android:background="#00000000"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/white"
     />
```

Comment: But in your LayoutOne  fragment you are just displaying a R.layout.layout_one xml file without attaching it to an adapter that holds some data to show in it.

Comment: how to use this adapter to show in one of the xml file list use suppose your layout_one.xml                                                mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
                    new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
                    new int[] { android.R.id.text1}, 0);

Comment: my fragment class is public class ContactsFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>